# getResourceAsStream in dynamically loaded jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, getresource

I kow there are dozens (if not hundreds) questions about Java's getResource/getResourceAsStream but i did not find any answers to my problem.

I load jars dynamically with: (`String path` is given)

```
File jar = new File(path);
URL url = new URL("file", "localhost", jar.getAbsolutePath());
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { url });
c = loader.loadClass(name);
```

Then within the jar i try to load a resource in the jar. This resource clearly exists in the jar and the whole procedure works if I just run the whole thing with a class loader in Eclipse. In a jar it does not work.$

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("resource.dat");
```

I tried every possible combination of `/packageName/resource.dat`, `packageName/resource.dat`, `/resource.dat` and `resource.dat`. They all throw a `stream closed` Exception.

The I tried debugging and ended up printing the URL of these files loaded via `getClass().getResource(path)`

This led to following URL and it does not look normal to me. Is it supposed to say "localhostC:..."?

```
jar:file://localhostC:\Users\******\export.jar!/packageName/resource.dat
```

Converting this URL also throws an Exception (`URISyntaxException`).

Is this URL really broken or am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the line:

```
URL url = new URL("file", "localhost", jar.getAbsolutePath());
```

to

```
URL url = new URL("file", null, jar.getAbsolutePath());
```

The host parameter in the URL constructor is not applicable in this case.

Comment: Thank you! This works. Still weird why it would add "localhost" in the getResource tag.

Comment: When I had `url = new URL[]{new URL("file:///" + jar.getAbsolutePath())};` - classLoader.getResourceAsStream return null for all entries in jar besides /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

Answer (score 2):

First, the `File` class has a [`toURI()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toURI--) method, so the preferred way to get a URL pointing to a file is:

```
URL url = new File(path).toURI().toURL();
```

So using this, the class loader:

```
File jar = new File(path);
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { jar.toURI().toURL() });
```

Next, when you want to load a resource for the jar, use a `Class` that is originating from the jar, so if you already loaded the `Class c`:

```
Class<?> c = loader.loadClass(classPathAndName);
URL resource = c.getResource("data.txt");
```

This will result in something like:

```
jar:file:/C:/test/testjar.jar!/testpkg/data.txt
```

Alternatively you can use the `ClassLoader` to get the resource like:

```
loader.getResoure(packageAndResourceName);
```

But note that this quoting from the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource-java.lang.String-):

> This method will first search the parent class loader for the resource; if the parent is `null` the path of the class loader built-in to the virtual machine is searched. That failing, this method will invoke [`findResource(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#findResource-java.lang.String-) to find the resource.